# Cast Dictionary<string, class> to IDictionary<string, interface>

Tags: c#, .net

I have a class that holds a dictionary of parameters:

```
public class Parameter : IExecutionParameter, IDesignerParameter
{
}

public interface IExecutionSettings
{
  IDictionary<string, IExecutionParameter> Parameters { get; }
}

public interface IDesignerSettings
{
  IDictionary<string, IDesignerParameter> Parameters { get; }
}

public class Settings : IExecutionSettings, IDesignerSettings
{
  private Dictionary<string, Parameter> _parameters;

  // TODO: Implement IExecutionSettings.Parameters
  // TODO: Implement IDesignerSettings.Parameters
}
```

I want to create explicit implementations of these interfaces (this I know how to do), but I can't figure out how to properly cast the dictionary.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If user adds something to one of the obtained `IDictionary`'ies, should it be added to you `Dictionary` too?

Comment: Yes, that was the intent, but as Jon Skeet pointed out, anything that implements a certain interface would be a valid value for the interface, but not for the underlying store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't, because it wouldn't be safe. Suppose you could cast `Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>` to `IDictionary<string, IDisposable>` - you'd then be able to put *any* `IDisposable` value in the dictionary via the latter reference, even though the actual dictionary can only hold `MemoryStream`-compatible references.

You could potentially create a readonly dictionary wrapper which delegates to an underlying dictionary for all reads, and fails on all writes. You could then wrap your `Dictionary<string, Parameter>` in two of these "view" dictionaries. It would be a bit of a pain, but doable. Whether or not that's the most appropriate approach in your case is a different matter.

Perhaps instead you should have:

```
public interface IExecutionSettings
{
    IExecutionParameter this[string key] { get; }
}

public interface IDesignerSettings
{
    IDesignerParameter this[string key] { get; }
}
```

You could easily implement both of those (explicitly) within `Settings`.

Comment: This is a very good point! I haven't thought about it. Thank you!

Comment: Would this alternative pose any risks, then: Create a base interface for these two, and set the dictionary to use that interface as a value type: `Dictionary<string, IParameter>` and `interface IParameter : IExecutionParameter, IDesignerParameter`, am I on a good track here?

Comment: Nope. Just realized that this doesn't accomplish anything. I could probably check that a certain item implements both interfaces for both properties, but this would easily grow out of control. I think I'll stay with read-only approach via indexers, as this will do fine for my scenario. Thanks again!